# How to create Onfido Webhook to verify customers

Tags: node.js, api, webhooks, hapi.js

I am trying to create  Web-hook to be notified about events that happen After creating Onfido Check for a customer from Back-end. While testing my Web-hook i am getting response as below:

```
{ resource_type: 'test_resource',
action: 'test_action',
object:
{ id: '1234-1234-2658-3698',
status: 'completed',
completed_at: '2018-03-12 07:06:48 +0000',
href: 'https://api.onfido.com/v2/test_sources//12343-11122-09290/reports/12345-23122-32123' } }
```

But i don't know What will be the Unique Key or ID (for ex.  ApplicantID or CheckID ) which we can save in our database earlier while creating Applicant or while create Check on Applicant and after getting response from Webhook we could update Customer status.

Comment: what you have pasted is the result of an test_event. This is not the output received for an check

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I receive something like

```
{
    payload: {
        action: "check.completed",
        resource_type: "check",
        object: {
            completed_at: "2018-08-15 13:36:30 UTC",
            href: "https://api.onfido.com/v2/applicants/<applicant_id>/checks/<check_id>",
            id: <check_id>,
            status: "complete"
        }
    }
}
```

So, Here is `applicant_id` and `check_id` in `payload.object.href` field and `check_id` in `payload.object.id` field. (Something like this described in https://documentation.onfido.com/#event-object)

You can know your `check_id` from `id` field in a response from `POST https://api.onfido.com/v2/applicants/{applicant_id}/checks` as described here: https://documentation.onfido.com/#create-check